# Connecting to Jupyter Instance with VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, google-dl-platform

I have a running Google Deep Learning VM, I set up an SSH tunnel and when I navigate to http://localhost:8080, I am connected to the running Jupyter Lab instance. Running the command `sudo service jupyter status`, tells me that the service is running correctly.

Now, I want to connect to the Jupyter instance with Visual Studio Code. I tried [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[P] and "Python: Specify Jupyter server URI" and entered http://localhost:8080 in the resulting prompt. However, I get an error message:

```
Failed to connect to remote Jupyter notebook.
Check that the Jupyter Server URI setting has a valid running server specified.
http://localhost:8080/
Error: Failed to connect to password protected server. Check that password is correct.
```

Unfortunately, the [documentation does not say very much](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter).

Has anybody experience with connecting VSCode to a remote server? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparently, you **have to** set a password.
I followed the instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/4z26o7/setup_and_configure_jupyter_how_to_set_up_a/) to create a hashed password. Then I edited my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file and edited the line `c.NotebookApp.password = '<my_super_secret_hash>'`. Eventually, I could connect with VSCode.